# How can I exclude certain file types when using Powershell and the PSCX Write-Zip cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, pscx

How can I exclude certain file types when using Powershell and the PSCX Write-Zip cmdlet?

Right now I'm using this:

```
Write-Zip -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder" -OutputPath
"C:\newDeploy\backup\Folder.zip" -IncludeEmptyDirectories -NoClobber -Level 1
```

I need it to include the directory structure in the ZIP and I also need to exclude certain file types (eg: .txt).

Thank you for your help :)

-Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can come in this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder"
Get-ChildItem . -r -Exclude *.txt | Write-Zip -OutputPath c:\temp\folder.zip -IncludeEmptyDirectories -NoClobber -Level 1
```

but this doesn't seem to be honoring the request to include empty dirs.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll just take out that IncludeEmptyDirectories - if they are empty I probably don't need them anyway :)